# Problem loading texture model in forge 1.8.9 mod

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

Im pretty new to coding mods, sorry if it is a simple fix.
this is the log output:
https://pastebin.com/gnFY6Fa3  here's the ModItems.java file

```
package slimer.mod.init;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.resources.model.ModelResourceLocation;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;
import slimer.mod.Reference;

public class ModItems {

public static Item copper_ingot; 

public static void init() {
    copper_ingot = new Item().setUnlocalizedName("copper_ingot");
}

public static void register() {
    registerItem(copper_ingot); 
}

public static void registerRenders() {
    registerRender(copper_ingot);   
}

public static void registerItem(Item item) {
    GameRegistry.registerItem(item, item.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
    System.out.println("Registered Item: " + item.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
}

public static void registerRender(Item item) {
    Minecraft.getMinecraft().getRenderItem().getItemModelMesher().register(item, 0, new ModelResourceLocation(Reference.MODID + ":" + item.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5), "inventory"));
}
```

}

if any other files need linking please say
thanks in advance

Edit:
Using Eclipse to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the MODID from Slimer to slimer and it worked